# Cross Domain Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, cross-domain

I'm aware there is a fair amount out there about this sort of thing, but I can't get mine working. I'm only worried about cross domain and not about sub domain.

I have 2 sites, **www.siteA.com** and **www.siteB.org** for example.

**SiteA** has a link to my registration page on **SiteB**.

On **SiteA** I have the following script (On my layoutpage/master):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '##AnalyticsIDA##']);
        _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function () {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    </script>
```

On **SiteB** I have the following script (On my layoutpage/master):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '##AnalyticsIDA##']);
        _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function () {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    </script>
```

I have a link on **SiteA**

```
<a href="www.siteB.org" onclick="_gaq.push(['_link', 'www.siteB.org']); return false;">testing</a>
```

This takes me to **www.siteB.org** with all the correct parameters (same as my **SiteA** cookie values), but **SiteB's** cookies have different values to **SiteA**.

**EDIT**

Futhermore, I've also tried using `_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'siteA.com']);` and `_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'siteB.com']);` but I still get new cookies on **siteB**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `_setDomainName` in your GA code? From the [Cross Domain docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#yourDomainName):

> (_setDomainName) Use this when you want to treat top- and sub-domains as one entity and track in the same profile. Also use this when you want to **track across multiple top-level domains** AND their sub-domains. In this case, you will need to using linking between the top-level domains, but not between the top-level domains and their sub-domains.

In your case, on **SiteA**

```
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '##AnalyticsIDA##']);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'siteA.com']);
    _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

and on **SiteB**

```
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '##AnalyticsIDA##']);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'siteB.com']);
    _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

Comment: Hi @mike, I've tried this to, but to no avail. I've also just taken the url params and appended them to my siteB url and still I get new cookies.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but did you clear your cookies on both sites before testing? Can you post the contents of the `__utmz` cookies? Maybe also the parameters on the __utm.gif requests...

Comment: I did indeed clear cookies. I'll post the content in a reply tomorrow.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the `onClick` to:

```js
onclick="_gaq.push(['_link', '.siteB.org']); return false;"
```